# Open a table on click of the another td in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4

I am new to react.

I have a table which is like,

```
const tableone = props => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
            <thead>
              <tr className="text-center">
                <th></th>
                <th scope="col">Recruiter Name
            </th>
                <th scope="col">Number of ID
            </th>
                <th scope="col">Yesterday's Final Score
            </th>
                <th scope="col">Score added today
            </th>
                <th scope="col">Updo Date Final Score
            </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="text-center">
                {props.data && props.data.length > 0 && props.data.map((item, key) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={key}>
                      <td align="center">
                        <input type="checkbox"/>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {item.name}
                      </td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.noc}</td>
                      <td>{item.final}</td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.today}</td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.upto}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, here on click of the first TD which is `item.name` , Now on click of this, I am trying to open a new table kind of `accordion`. So,

My other table is in an

```
another component.

const JobsTable = props => {
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
        <thead>
          <tr className="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Technology
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Total Resumes
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Job Title
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Total Score
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Average Score
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default JobsTable;
```

So, Here How can I render this component onClick of that `TD` in a react way. I have tried with one library of reacting accordion but I think, using a library for this is not a good Idea. So, Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: `using a library for this is not a good Idea`, why not?

Comment: I mean if using bootstrap we can do so that was the reason. Otherwise no issue. As am totally new to this Sorry If am wronng

Comment: No problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t4lrov. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be the following:

Change your item name cell to add the interaction:

```
<td onClick={()=>this.toggleJobsTable()}>
    {item.name}
</td>
```

The function:

```
toggleJobsTable() {
   this.setState({
      jobsTableVisible: !this.state.jobsTableVisible
   });
}
```

Don't forget to set the initial value of the jobsTableVisible as false in the tableone component's state. Add a constructor to the component and set the initial the state

```
this.state = {
    jobsTableVisible: false
}
```

Then in the JobsTable component before the return add a check:

```
let visibleClass = " hidden";
if (this.props.jobsTableVisible) {
    visibleClass = "";
}
```

And update this part:

```
<div className="table-responsive">
```

to this:

```
<div className={"table-responsive"+visibleClass}>
```

Don't forget to pass the jobsTableVisible property to the JobsTable and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `state activeId and display innertable`. This is working example.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Rama singh1",
    noc: "noc1",
    final: "final1",
    today: "today1",
    upto: "upto1"
  },
  {
    name: "Rama singh2",
    noc: "noc2",
    final: "final2",
    today: "today2",
    upto: "upto2"
  },
  {
    name: "Rama singh3",
    noc: "noc3",
    final: "final3",
    today: "today3",
    upto: "upto3"
  },
  {
    name: "Rama singh4",
    noc: "noc4",
    final: "final4",
    today: "today4",
    upto: "upto4"
  }
];

const JobsTable = props => (
  <div className="table-responsive">
    <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
      <thead>
        <tr className="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Technology</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Resumes</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Score</th>
          <th scope="col">Average Score</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody />
    </table>
  </div>
);
const Tableone = props => (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12">
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
          <thead>
            <tr className="text-center">
              <th />
              <th scope="col">Recruiter Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Number of ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Yesterday's Final Score</th>
              <th scope="col">Score added today</th>
              <th scope="col">Updo Date Final Score</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="text-center">
            {props.data &&
              props.data.length > 0 &&
              props.data.map((item, key) => {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment key={key}>
                    <tr key={key} onClick={() => props.clickHandler(key)}>
                      <td align="center">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                      </td>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.noc}</td>
                      <td>{item.final}</td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.today}</td>
                      <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.upto}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {props.activeId === key ? (
                      <tr>
                        <JobsTable />
                      </tr>
                    ) : null}
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeId: ""
  };
  clickHandler = id => {
    if (id === this.state.activeId) this.setState({ activeId: "" });
    else this.setState({ activeId: id });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Tableone
        data={data}
        activeId={this.state.activeId}
        clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
      />
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code.

```
const JobsTable = props => {
      return (
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
            <thead>
              <tr className="text-center">
                <th scope="col">Technology</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Resumes</th>
                <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Score</th>
                <th scope="col">Average Score</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody />
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    };

    class Tableone extends React.Component {
      constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
          showAcc: false
        };
      }

      toggleJobs = () => {
        this.setState({ showAcc: !this.state.showAcc });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-hover" id="dashboard">
                  <thead>
                    <tr className="text-center">
                      <th />
                      <th scope="col">Recruiter Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Number of ID</th>
                      <th scope="col">Yesterday's Final Score</th>
                      <th scope="col">Score added today</th>
                      <th scope="col">Updo Date Final Score</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody className="text-center">
                    {this.props.data &&
                      this.props.data.length > 0 &&
                      this.props.data.map((item, key) => {
                        return (
                          <tr key={key}>
                            <td align="center">
                              <input type="checkbox" />
                            </td>
                            <td onClick={this.toggleJobs}>
                              {item.name}
                              <div>
                              {this.state.showAcc && <JobsTable />}
                              </div>

                            </td>
                            <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.noc}</td>
                            <td>{item.final}</td>
                            <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.today}</td>
                            <td className="font-weight-bold">{item.upto}</td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```